# Is there an es-lint or similar rule for disabling `extends`

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I want to use ES2015 classes, but don't want any inheritance to get into our codebase. Is there a custom eslint rule somewhere like "no-extends" or "no-inheritance" so people can't do `class A extends B {}`?

I searched for this quite a bit, but think I might be using the wrong search terms.

Comment: https://github.com/wesbaker/eslint-plugin-class-extends

Comment: "*I don't want any inheritance to sneak into our codebase*" - how would it *sneak* in there? Someone has to make the conscious decision to use inheritance. There's nothing wrong with using the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Bergi changed "sneak" into the more neutral "get."

Comment: Still it sounds like you are trying to ban hammers for the sole reason that someone might want to use them on screws, ignoring that there might also be nails. OK, if there are devs on your team who will think "*No idea how to approach this, I'll try inheritance*", you have my deepest sympathy, but I don't think it's a problem you can fix with a linter. (In that case I'd also recommend to ban `class`, to force them to explore simpler solutions first)

Comment: But it's just syntactic sugar for `prototype`. How unlucky. Beware of sneaky OOP scoundrels.

Comment: @31piy You should to post that as an answer. Unless we want to close as off-topic for being a software recommendation question :-)

Comment: @Bergi -- Wasn't sure if that would solve the problem, and the documentation was too little to post an answer without trying it first.

Comment: @Bergi the question is "how do I accomplish X", not "do you agree X is a reasonable goal"? The question can be answered in a a clear, objective way.
Many lint rules are somewhat subjective, which is independent of how to implement them.

Comment: @MaxHeiber I was not suggesting it should be closed for being opinion-based (which it is not), but for being borderline to a library recommendation: "*Is there a custom eslint rule somewhere*" (instead of "*How do I implement a rule that …*").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule to ban inheritance like so (implemented in JS syntax here):

```js
rules: {
  'no-restricted-syntax': [
    'error',
    {
      selector: 'ClassDeclaration[superClass]',
      message: "Extending other classes via inheritance isn't allowed. Use composition instead.",
    },
  ],
},
```

The `message` is optional, but helps with DX.